# How to parse hibernate request with backslash?

Tags: database, hibernate

I'm trying to get record from database with hibernate query:

```
   File f = new File("D:/javaTest/2/vas/tumblr_nxxv9dOz881u3reero1_1280.jpg");
   Query q = session.createQuery("FROM FileData E WHERE E.name = 'tumblr_nxxv9dOz881u3reero1_1280.jpg' and E.path= "
   + f.getPath() + "' and  E.userId=9");
```

but receive:
 `Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.QueryException: unexpected char: '\' [FROM trainee.model.FileData E WHERE E.name = 'tumblr_nxxv9dOz881u3reero1_1280.jpg' and E.path= D:\javaTest\2\vas\tumblr_nxxv9dOz881u3reero1_1280.jpg' and  E.userId=9]`
Records file path in database stored from `file.getPath()` method. 
As I understand hiberante can't handle `\`
How to fix my problem without changing database record file path from `D:\javaTest\2\vas\tumblr_nxxv9dOz881u3reero1_1280.jpg'` to `D:/javaTest/2/vas/tumblr_nxxv9dOz881u3reero1_1280.jpg'`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use parameters

```
String v = "\\s";
Query q = session.createQuery("from FileData where path = :v and ...");
q.setParameter("v", v);
```

**TEST**

Tag table [had an existing test table so reused it]

[image: Table]

```
Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
String v = "D:\\javaTest\\2\\vas\\tumblr_nxxv9dOz881u3reero1_1280.jpg";
Query q = session.createQuery("from Tag where name = :v");
q.setParameter("v", v);
```

output

```
Hibernate: select tag0_.tag_id as tag_id1_3_, tag0_.tag_name as tag_name2_3_, tag0_.tag_props as tag_prop3_3_ from tag tag0_ where tag0_.tag_name=?
Tag [id=1, name=D:\javaTest\2\vas\tumblr_nxxv9dOz881u3reero1_1280.jpg]
```